# I have a gitignore file that doesn't ignore a folder since I previously commited and pushed it

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I have a .gitignore file that ignores a folder. When I commit and push it, it says:

> remote: error: File /myFolder/fild.tz is 452.27 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100 MB

even though I ignored the folder. I tried doing:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch <file/dir>' HEAD
```

but it still looks for the file when I commit and push it. 
I made another repository and copy and pasted my project to another folder locally and intialized a .git with the gitignore file. This time, it pushes without the folder. How can I push without it looking for it?

Comment: "but it still looks for the file when I commit and push it"—well if you commit it again after doing `filter-branch` it's going to be included in your repo. What are you actually trying to accomplish? This may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627).

Comment: "This time, it pushes without the folder. How can I push without it looking for it?" (a) Git doesn't care about empty folders. (b) Pushing doesn't "look for", or operate on, files at all. It operates on _commits_. Make sure your _commits_ reflect what you actually want them to contain and your pushes should work automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already committed the file, it is in the index and `.gitignore` can't do anything about it. You need to remove that file from the index with `git rm`. If you want to save the file in your working copy, use `git rm --cached`.

Comment: OP says they have already done this via `git filter-branch` but they go on to say "When I commit and push it", which makes it sound like they're tracking the file again afterwards. They need to be more clear about what, _exactly_, they are doing. Otherwise this is not answerable.